# Click outside a modal to toggle a CSS attribute with JS

Tags: javascript

When the hamburger menu is open, I am trying to allow a click-off screen to toggle the visibility attribute. The other solutions I have seen I do not understand and have been unable to integrate into my code.

The code thus far will either toggle the visibility on click OR toggle visibility when pushing the menu button. With the click off modal event clicking on the screen (but not the menu button) will open and close the modal menu. If you get rid of the click off modal event then the menu button will work.

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-toggle");
const primaryNavigation = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation");
let dataVisible = false;

//Reference 1: Click off modal
document.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (dataVisible) {
    primaryNavigation.toggleAttribute("data-visible");
    dataVisible;
  }
});

//Reference 2: Menu button
navToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
  primaryNavigation.hasAttribute("data-visible")
    ? navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false)
    : navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
  primaryNavigation.toggleAttribute("data-visible");
  dataVisible;
});

dataVisible = function () {
  dataVisible = dataVisible ? false : true;
};
```

```css
.mobile-nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .primary-navigation {
    display: none;
    /* position: fixed; */
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 2em;

    width: auto;
    max-width: 25rem;
    padding: var(--size-300);
    background: var(--accent-primary);
    border-radius: var(--size-100);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.486);
  }

  .navigation::before[data-overlay] {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0 0 0 / 0), rgb(0 0 0 / 0.8));
  }

  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
    /* gap: var(--size-400) !important; */
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .nav-list li {
    padding: 0.5rem 7ch;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .nav-list li:hover {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .primary-navigation[data-visible] {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: blue;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  .mobile-nav-toggle .icon-close {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">
    <button class="mobile-nav-toggle">Menu</button>
                <nav class="primary-navigation" id="primary-navigation">
              <div class="nav-logo"> </div>
              <div>
                <ul role="list" class="nav-list" aria-label="primary">
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Buy Now</a></li>   
            </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By *"click off-screen"* you mean "click outside of a specific element"?

Comment: Yes, specifically clicking outside of the modal menu

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).